# Vue.js and Javascript async function call in Computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon,

I have a computed value that gets an array of data that comes to the component as props, it then does an extra check on the data and renders that data that comes in as props on the front end.

For example the prop it recieves is an array of objects.

I would like to add in my Computed property, code that will take this prop as an array of object, loop through the array of objects, and add a new property to each of the objects. This new property will be the result of an API Call.

For an example, I would like to do the following below in the computed value

```
for (var index = 0; index <= this.propData.length; index++) {
            this.propData[index].useful = await axios('service1')
          }
        }
```

Is there a way to implement this? thank you

Comment: This is a wrong choice. Computeds are synchronous (unless you want them to be promises, which is possible but unlikely). What you ask about is a watcher

Comment: Instead of using computed, use a watcher. Watch for changes in whatever prop you need, and then asynchronously populate a new copy of that data. You might want to consider making a single fetch request for all your items, instead of multiple ones, to reduce the number of HTTP connections and server calls.